# I have a loop that displays 10 values: 1.0, 1.1,1.2, etc. how can I put those values into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops, iterator

I have a loop that displays 10 values: 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, etc.:

```
int i = 0;
int x = 10;
for(i;i>x;i++)
{
   System.out.println(x);
}
```

but instead of displaying the values, I want to put them in an array. How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a generic array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Your loop does not do what you claim.

Comment: Your loop does not execute once, since `i > x` is `false`. You meant `i < x`.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
// You want x ints.
int x = 10;

// Make an array big enough to hold x ints.
int[] array = new int[x];

// Loop x times.
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {

   // Put the next number into the array.
   array[i] = i;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

first your way in writing for loop is need to be more clean

it should :

```
 for(int i=0; i > x; i++){
   System.out.println(x);
 }
```

second your boolean condition in for loop isn't true because `x=10` is always bigger than `i=0` so it won't print any thing.

third to put the values in array :

simply define array : `int[] numbers = new int[size of array];`

then put each value inside the index `i` of array :

```
numbers[i] = i;
```

finally for loop will be like:

```
for(int i=0; i < x; i++){
       numbers[i] = i;
}
```